# No errors reading source files, but wp_get_current_user() cannot be referenced

Tags: php, wordpress

The error message is as follows

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()
```

The executed php file is below.

**tweet.php**

```php
<?
require_once("pluggable.php");
require_once("codebird.php");

\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$wp_user_id = $current_user->ID;
$user_info = get_userdata($wp_user_id);
$twitter_id = get_user_meta($wp_user_id, "twitter_id", true);
$access_token = get_user_meta($wp_user_id, "twitter_access_token", true);
$access_token_secret = get_user_meta($wp_user_id, "twitter_access_token_secret", true);

$cb->setToken($access_token, $access_token_secret);

$media_id = $cb->media_upload(array(
  "media" => $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]
))->media_id_string;

$params = array(
  "status" => $_POST["text"],
  "media_ids" => $media_id
);
$result = $cb->statuses_update($params);

echo json_encode($result);
```

This tweet.php and pluggable.php are placed on the same level.
Why can't wp_get_current_user refer to it?

It is accessed in the following manner.
Error content is recognized by looking at the contents of xhr.

```php
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
var response = xhr.responseText;
}
}
xhr.open("POST", "wp/wp-includes/tweet.php", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

**Additional information:**

```
Content URL: /wp/wp-content
Include URL: /wp/wp-includes/
Template URL: /wp/wp-content/themes/keni80_wp_standard_all_202102011532
Stylesheet URL: /wp/wp-content/themes/keni8-child
WordPress Version: 6.1.1
PHP Version: 7.4.28
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) shoppingmode AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.61
Server Software: Apache
Server Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Language: ja,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Theme Name: Keni8.0
Version: 8.0.1.4
Category Count: 33
Tag Count: 310
User Count: 4
Child Theme Name: Keni8.0 (Child Theme)
Version: 8.0.0.0
```

**Plugins in use:**

```
Advanced Editor Tools (previously TinyMCE Advanced) 5.6.0
Akismet Anti-Spam 5.0.2
codoc 0.9.48
Enhanced Media Library 2.8.9
EWWW Image Optimizer 6.9.3
Otter - Page Builder Blocks & Extensions for Gutenberg 2.1.6
Really Simple SSL 6.0.14
Regenerate Thumbnails 3.1.5
Social Login, Social Sharing by miniOrange 7.5.14
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore 1.22.24
WP-CopyProtect [Protect your blog posts] 3.1.0
WP Fastest Cache 1.0.9
WP Multibyte Patch 2.9
```

Please note that I am using a translation tool for this question, so the English may be inaccurate. Please understand.

Comment: where / how do you include this `tweet.php`?

Comment: Just want the ID (and nothing else)? Just use [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) instead

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

tweet.php in the /wp/wp-includes directory. (using FFFTP software).
Nothing else is done in particular.
The following files used within tweet.php are also located in /wp/wp-includes.

・pluggable.php
・codebird.php

I am not getting an error that pluggable.php itself cannot be referenced.

 I tried using get_current_user_id() but got the same undefined error.

Comment: Additional information is being added.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the following to tweet.php

require_once('../wp-load.php');